# ServiceEventSource and Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Following a very simple code to play with the exception handling and logging in Service Fabric:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Entered 'GetAll' method");

    IActionResult result = null;
    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

    try
    {
        using (CustomersContext context = new CustomersContext(connectionString))
        {
            list = context.Customers.Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false).ToList<Customer>();
        }
        result = Json(list);

        throw new ArgumentException("Argument exception", new NullReferenceException("Null reference exception"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Exception: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
    }
    finally
    {
        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Exiting 'GetAll' method");
    }
    return result;
}
```

My question is: why this line of code at the beginning

`ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Entered 'GetAll' method");`

and this line of code in finally block

`ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Exiting 'GetAll' method");`

work fine and log entry in Diagnostic Events, while this one in catch block

`ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Exception: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));`

has the following error: "ServiceEventSource error CS0103: The name 'ServiceEventSource' does not exist in the current context"?

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! Answering your own question is not forbidden (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

Analyzing the signature and code of the called method, we note one thing:

```
public void ServiceMessage(ServiceContext serviceContext, string message, params objects[] args)
```

This means that message parameter is used in a string.Format method.

My problem was that passing a Json string, with "{" and "}" characters, it throws an exception because it doesn't recognize the format.